# Django foreignKey that doesn't use model's primary key to match to foreign object's primary key?

Tags: django, foreign-keys

Lets say I have two models that look like this:

```
ModelA
    uuid (primary key)
    id

ModelB
    id (primary key)
    size
```

I want to add a field to ModelA. I want this field to be a ForeignKey that joins on ModelA.id == ModelB.id.

I've searched all throughout the Django Docs and have only found how to change the foreign object's field used in the join, but I haven't found a way to change "this" object's field used in the join.

Is it possible to specify a non primary key field from "this" object that is used to create a foreign key by being joined on a matching primary key from the foreign object?

Answer (score 0):

[ForeignKey.to_field](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.ForeignKey.to_field)

```
ModelA
    uuid (primary key) unique=True
    id

ModelB
    id (primary key)
    size
    modela = ForeignKey(ModelA, to_field='uuid')
```